# Highlight each row when selecting multiple rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I'm using the this Jquery code to select multiple rows at once. As you see I tried changing the background color with the code "lastChecked.style.background = "yellow";" but it's not working. How do I do this?

```
var lastChecked = null;

$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.chkbox').click(function(event) {
                if(!lastChecked) {
                        lastChecked = this;
                        return;
                }

                if(event.shiftKey) {
                    var start = $('.chkbox').index(this);
                    var end = $('.chkbox').index(lastChecked);

                    for(i=Math.min(start,end);i<=Math.max(start,end);i++) {
                                $('.chkbox')[i].checked = lastChecked.checked;
                                lastChecked.style.background = "yellow";
                        }
                }

                lastChecked = this;
        });
});
```

Here's all of the code used:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Most Common Calls | CPRS Help{% endblock %}
{% block script %}
<script type="text/javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
function highlight_row(row_id,checkbox)
{
  var row = document.getElementById(row_id);
  row.style.background = checkbox.checked ? "yellow" : ""; 
}

function unhighlight_row(row_id)
{
  var row = document.getElementById(row_id);
  row.style.background = "white"; // background yellow
}
/*]]>*/
</script>
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<h2>Most Common Calls</h2>
<form action="/mark_as_uninteresting/" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<table class="calls">
<tr><th style="width:30px">N</th><th>Word</th><th style="width:150px;"><input class="searchbutton" type="submit" value="Mark as Uninteresting" /></th></tr>
{% for word in word_frequencies %}
<tr id="row_{{ forloop.counter }}"><td>{{ word.n }}</td><td style="padding:0;"><a href="/search/?q={{ word.word }}" style="padding:5px;display:block;color:blue;">{{ word.word }}</a></td><td style="text-align:center"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_{{ word.id }}" onclick="highlight_row('row_{{ forloop.counter }}',this)" id="id_chk{{ forloop.counter }}" class="chkbox" /></td></tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/media/js/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var lastChecked = null;

    $(document).ready(function() {

            $('.chkbox').click(function(event) {
                    if(!lastChecked) {
                            lastChecked = this;
                            return;
                    }

                    if(event.shiftKey) {
                        var start = $('.chkbox').index(this);
                        var end = $('.chkbox').index(lastChecked);

                        for(i=Math.min(start,end);i<=Math.max(start,end);i++) {
                                    $('.chkbox')[i].checked = lastChecked.checked;
                            }
                    }

                    lastChecked = this;
            });
    });
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: lastChecked = $(this);  and lastChecked.css("background-color","yellow") or change classname (better)

Comment: Show some html. Preferably here: http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: @Tim have a look here http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/DukXj/1/

Comment: Thank you. I added all of the code used.

Comment: Could you post the html that's sent to the browser (View Source), since that's what JavaScript works with. Also: with your 'query' tag, did you mean 'jquery'? (Not suggesting you **should** use jQuery, but you seem to be using it, and the 'query' tag seems otherwise unrelated to your question.)

Comment: Are you trying to set only "lastchecked" to yellow, or all the affected checkboxes?

Comment: I'm trying to set the background of the TR for all of the affected checkboxes to yellow.

Comment: see full HTML source code at [link](http://pastebin.com/3skM51fa)

Comment: Seems to work. What is the issue?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### UPDATED SOLUTION:

Ok, now that your issue is more clear, here is the correct solution:

If you want the rows to have a background color when selecting using the shift key, you need to change this line:

```
lastChecked.style.background = "yellow";
```

to →

```
$('.chkbox')[i].parentNode.style.backgroundColor='yellow';
```

OR

```
$('.chkbox').eq(i).parents('tr').style.backgroundColor='yellow';
```

Your version tries to set the background color on the checkbox. This is impossible. You need to select the checkbox's parent Node.

The first version in my solution will target the checkbox's immediate parent. This is ok to use in your case if your `<tr>`'s only go one level deep. If, however, your `<tr>`'s can go deeper (i.e. a checkbox might be in a `<span>` which is then inside the `<tr>`) you should use the second version, which searches the checkbox's ancestors for a `<tr>` element, then sets *its* background.

Comment: can you give a little more background? what does your markup look like?

Comment: style.background and style.backgroundColor are the same in this case: http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/DukXj/

Comment: what is the class "chkbox" assigned to? If it is an `<input type="checkbox">`, then background color cannot be set on it.

Comment: Interesting, @ampersand - then this is really needed? http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/DukXj/1/

Comment: I've never been able to change the bg color,@mplungian. Even your last fiddle doesn't style the actual checkbox color, only the area around it...

Comment: Hi Tim, I took a look at what you provided and it's working fine for me in Safari 5.0.2: http://jsfiddle.net/ampersand/9YwJT/. Each tr gets a yellow background after the checkbox is checked. What happens when __you__ run this?

Comment: It must be an issue with Chrome.

Comment: When I select many rows at once, only the first and last rows are highlighted yellow.

Comment: Ok, I finally understand what behavior you were looking for. Your original question is not clear. I'll update my solution with the correct answer.